# Хрен and phrases in which it is involved

Tags: словоупотребление, мат, phrase

What is the English equivalent of the following phrases: "Ни хрена не делаешь", "Какого хрена?", "Пошёл на хрен", "Не хрена тебе здесь делать", "Ты совсем охренел".

Comment: Another question concerning usage of [хрен](http://russian.stackexchange.com/q/2912/551).

Answer (score 5):

[**Хрен**](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD) (see meaning 3) is a euphemism for **хуй**, "prick", and all those phrases can be used with **хуй**, too. In English, "fuck" is usually used in that meaning, so:

> Ни хрена не делаешь. - You aren't doing a fuck.
>
> Какого хрена? - What the fuck?
>
> Пошёл на хрен. - Fuck off. / Fuck you.
>
> Не хрена тебе здесь делать. - You have not a fuck to do here.

Comment: "Ни черта не делаешь", "какого чёрта", "пошёл к чёрту", "какого чёрта ты здесь делаешь?" Можно много чего наподставлять, но в статье по ссылке примеры ведь совсем другие.

Answer (score 4):

NOTE: These are based on a personal usage growing up...not a dictionary definition. So your mileage may vary :)

> "Ни хрена не делаешь" - You are doing nothing ( minor vulgar/impolite intonation ).

- "Ни чего не делаешь" = You are doing nothing ( no vulgarity implied ).
- "You lazy sack of potatoes" - would be a slang/colloquial way to say this phrase.

> "Какого хрена?" - "Why the heck [would you do/say that]?" ( minor vulgar/impolite intonation ).

> "Пошёл на хрен" - "Go to hell"

- In this case "hell" is a bit strong, but I can't come up with a closer equivalent ).

> "Не хрена тебе здесь делать" - It's a combination of "You shouldn't be here" and "What the [hell | heck] are you doing here?" ( minor vulgar/impolite intonation ).

> "Ты совсем охренел" - "You've got some nerve" or "You are crazy" ( minor vulgar/impolite intonation ).

P.S. хрен is technically 'horseradish' so imagine applying a 'bitter' connotation  to make these phrases slightly impolite/vulgar.

Comment: I disagree on this, "хрен" is definitely less vulgar than the strong word it stands for, whil still being inappropriate to use with strangers (who may actually get angry). The use of such words in the order of increasing obscenity is rougly *фиг→хрен→жопа→хер→х%&*, with "фиг" being a mild swear word more or less suitable even for your stereotypical goody-two shoes girl.

Comment: This is really interesting, definitely not how I grew up hearing it, now I'm curious does anyone know what's the history of хрен becoming vulgar ?